# Perhaps the answer is hidden in the stars?

Tags: riddle

When you get right down to it, you'll find the hidden robot pretty quickly. Don't forget to write two down, as well.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The robot concealed in this riddle is:

> The droid **R2D2** from [*Star Wars*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R2-D2).

*When you get right down to it, you'll find the hidden robot pretty quickly.*

> 'When you get **right** (R) **down** (D) **to** (2) it' yields 'RD2'.

*Don't forget to write two down, as well.*

> Add ('write down') another '2' between the 'R' and 'D', and you have **R2D2**.

Re the title:

> R2D2 is a character in the ***Star** Wars* movie franchise.

<sub>PS In addition to its use as outlined above, the second sentence of the riddle can also be seen as pointing towards the answer in a different way:</sub>

> <sub>'write two down, as well' could be directly parsed as: write (**R** - since 'writing' is one of '[the three R's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_three_Rs)') two (**2**) down (**D**), as well ('too' - **2**).</sub>

Comment: Well done :) "write two down, as well" could also follow the same logic as the first part, if you use a homophone for "write" and a synonym of "as well"

Comment: @simonalexander2005 That's true - I'll remark on that in the answer...

Answer (score 2):

Hidden in the stars

> I think the answer is **Pollux** in the constellation Gemini

right down

> This depends on your viewpoint but if you arrange the twins to look like human figures, Pollux is on the right

hidden robot

> The twins look more like stick men (or robots) than they do like humans. [image]

write two

> There are **two** "robots" and if you write "Pollux" in certain scripts, you will see a Roman II.  [image]